# Best (Most Efficient) Way to get a Contact's Photo in Android

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I am pulling information from the contacts, and want to display the associated photo (if there is one). There seem to be several ways to do it:

1. Get the user's ID, and then:

   Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
   InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
2. You can retrieve the user's PHOTO_ID. I haven't dug into the exact steps, but presumably, there's a way to use the PHOTO_ID to get the photo.
3. There's also a PHOTO_URI, and again, I assume there's a way to use that to get the photo.

Right now, my code is using the method 1, and it's working just fine. What I'm wondering is this:  Is method 2 or 3 (or one I haven't read about) faster/more efficient? I naturally want to make my app as fast as possible. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo` contains some sample code, but my **guess** is that it's pretty much what `openContactPhotoInputStream` is doing for you.